# react-router v4 and NavLink - routes need to be in a separate component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Clicking on a NavLink was not updating my app. The NavLink is expected to update a todos list based on a filter link.

The solution for that was to extract the route into a separate stateless functional component :

```
const MyRoutes = () => (
    <Route path='/:filter?' component={App} />
);

const Root = ({store}) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <MyRoutes/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

This works.

But with the same Route inside the Router, the NavLink does not trigger a new todo list.

What can explain that I have to extract the route into a separate component ?

Comment: What doesn't work include in your post as an example.

Comment: The App component is a todo list, with a link to update the todos based on a filter, passed as the "filter" param.  The link renders the updated todos only if the route is extracted into the separate "MyRoutes" component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this. The right way is importing the `Switch` from `react-router-dom`, and use it like this:

```
import { Switch, BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const Root = ({store}) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/:filter' component={App} />
            </Switch> 
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

If you want to define a main Route, you need to use the `exact` prop of the component `Route`:

```
<Route exact path='/:filter' component={App} />
```

**EDIT:** To use the `exact`, your route needs to be inside a `Switch`

Comment: Thanks! It works with your Switch example.  But why the Switch is not needed when I extract to a separate component ?

Comment: Simply specify "exact" won't work.  The Switch is needed.

Comment: I  guess that "Route" doesn't renders anything by itself. Switch does the rendering.     Having my route in a separate component implies a rendering.

Comment: The `Route` has a render method, but you need something to change what `component` is rendered according to the `Route`. And that's why we use the `Switch`.